# Unable to open Tabular project file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

Hi there I am having an same issue in opening a tabular project file in Visual Studio. With the.smproj file I am getting an incompatible error stating that the application is not installed.

The error message I am getting on the migration report is as follows:
"XXX".smproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. 
​I have tried opening this in VS 2015, 2017 and 2019.

I have installed the following extensions:

- Microsoft Integration Services Projects (VS 2017)
- SQL Server Integration Services Projects (VS 2019)

In all the versions I am unable to access this project, with the same incompatible error.

Any guidance anyone can provide on the above would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You should install the [Microsoft Analysis Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects) extension (in Visual Studio 2019 or Visual Studio 2017).

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2022 add extension gallery to download the preview pack using the extensions tools blue link in the tools and extensions popup window - Use this URL for the gallery (http://aka.ms/ProBI-VSIX2022) and name it (Microsoft BI VSIX Preview)

Source:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects